# how to tell get-iplayer to download a list of numbers?

Tags: bash

Following on from Q21218074, I'm now trying to ask a question for you to input some program numbers, which get-iplayer will then read and download. So far, I've got this -

```
#!/bin/bash
{   
    read -n3 -p "Please input the tv programme numbers to download " 'textbox'
    case "$ynq" in
    [Yy]* ) get-iplayer --get "textbox";; 
    [Nn]* ) echo;;
    [Qq]* ) exit;;
    * ) echo "Please answer yes or no. ";;
    esac
}
```

You have to enter the program numbers in the textbox, and the script reads the numbers and passes them to get-iplayer, but how please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this will answer your question, but it seems like you want this

```
read -n3 -p "Please input the tv programme numbers to download " 'textbox'
case "$textbox" in
  [Yy]* ) get-iplayer --get "$textbox";; 
  [Nn]* ) echo;;
  [Qq]* ) exit;;
  * ) echo "Please answer yes or no. ";;
esac
```

Note in your case you're doing your case statement over a variable you haven't defined (unless you have it elsewhere) and `textbox` is a variable so should have `$` in-front of it when you pass it to get-iplayer.

Comment: Try again   This is the final working lines    `                            read -n100 -p "Please input the tv programme numbers to download " 'textbox'  
      case '$textbox' in  
      ['$textbox']* ) cd /media/$USER/back2/proggies/; /usr/bin/get-    iplayer --get $textbox;;                                          although the formatting is up the creek.                            Thanks for starting me off. :)